# Order by name if repeat

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to sort the bars in descending order by value and if the value is repeated the name of the city must appear in alphabetical order

```
library(plotly)

city   <- c("Paris", "New York", "Rio", "Salvador", "Curitiba", "Natal")
value  <- c(10,20,30,10,10,10)

data   <- data.frame(city, value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data$city <- factor(data$city, levels = unique(data$city)[order(data$value, decreasing = FALSE)])


fig <- plot_ly(y = data$city, x = data$value, type = "bar", orientation = 'h')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be achieved using order function on dataframe. Applies order on value column, (-) sign indicates decreasing, and then on city name

```
data_ordered <- data[order(-data$value, data$city),]
data_ordered
     city value
3      Rio    30
2 New York    20
5 Curitiba    10
6    Natal    10
1    Paris    10
4 Salvador    10

data_ordered$city <- factor(data_ordered$city, levels = data_ordered$city)

plot_ly(y = data_ordered$city, x = data_ordered$value, type = "bar", orientation = 'h') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(autorange = "reversed"))
```

Comment: perfect, this orders the data.frame the way I want it, but the figure generated by polt_ly is not as desired

Comment: I've updated my answer to sort the issue with plot_ly to order the vertical axis correctly. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using tidyverse, i suggest that :

```
library(tidyverse)

city   <- c("Paris", "New York", "Rio", "Salvador", "Curitiba", "Natal")
value  <- c(10,20,30,10,10,10)

data   <- data.frame(city, value)
db <- as_tibble(data)

db %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(city, -value), y=value))+
  geom_col()
```

The "reorder" function in the definition of "x" make what you want, and the alphabetical order is respected.

To make this graph vertically, add coord_flip in the end.
The "-value" can be switch to "value" if you want reorder

```
library(tidyverse)

city   <- c("Paris", "New York", "Rio", "Salvador", "Curitiba", "Natal", "Zoo", "Aaa")
value  <- c(10,20,30,10,10,10,10,10)

data   <- data.frame(city, value)
db <- as_tibble(data)

db %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(city, value), y=value))+
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: this works with the bars vertically, but with the bars horizontally the order is from smallest to largest. Perhaps this should have been my question since I had already arrived at this

Comment: To obtain what you want, add +coord_flip () in the end, and remove the "-" in front of value.

Comment: cities with equal values ​​are ordered from Z-A

Comment: I managed to solve by adding  `db$city <- factor(db$city, levels = db$city)`